# Read/write java.util.Properties from .Net

Tags: java, .net, properties

Is there a .NET class or mechanism that is able to read and write files stored from `java.util.Properties` in XML format, while retaining the compatibility to the Java class?

The reason is that I want to exchange some data between a Java and .NET application using Properties objects. I know there are other ways to exchange data, but this is the situation that I have and cannot/don't want to change at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I need to read/write the XML representation.